# Red5 Server and PHP issues

Tags: php, red5

- I have red5-server-1.0.10 unzipped from tarball into a directory on my Xubuntu 18.04 OS.
- All necessary prerequisites namely openjdk-8-jre installed. The red5 server launches successfully.
- http://localhost:5080 red5 testpage successfully launched when executed in web browser.
- I also have a directory full of PHP files - from a website called www.videowhisper.com - of videowhispers video conference PHP platform.
- Apache2 installed with prerequisites PHP and flash player.

Heres the issue
The video conference website can successfully reach and connect to the RMTP server (red5). My router has all the necessary TCP ports forwarded for communication between router and apache2 server

- Inside the video conference page I can see the following output

  Connecting to RMTP Server
  NetConnection.Connect.Success

  Your Download (playback from server) connection speed
  Download Bandwidth: 6484 Kbps (810 Kb/s)
  Download Test Latency: 117ms 
  NetConnection.Call.Failed
- My Red5 Server Output in Xubuntu Terminal  says

  [INFO] [NioProcessor-5] com.videowhisper.Application - W3C x-category:session x-event:disconnect c-ip:192.168.0.1 c-client-id:3
  [INFO] [NioProcessor-6] com.videowhisper.Application - W3C x-category:session x-event:connect c-ip:192.168.0.1 c-client-id:4

  [ERROR] [NioProcessor-6] org.red5.server.service.ServiceInvoker - Method onClientBWCheck with parameters [0.34309581108391285, 0.9987998637370765, 0.24372699530795217, 0.7745033204555511, 0.5961467670276761, 0.3997542317956686, 0.7898974381387234, 0.8035499476827681, 0.532193582970649, 0.2779586990363896, 0.6019076551310718, 0.2508636941201985, 0.9328633435070515, 0.57703897356987, 0.7307708766311407, 0.2506825444288552, 0.8760253265500069, 0.7146183280274272, 0.6105958418920636, 0.6040642079897225, 0.12148901354521513, 0.27246888261288404, 0.8048107782378793, 0.9318704945035279, 0.7904520924203098, 0.5925731835886836]] not found in com.videowhisper.Application@2afd39c5

Why am I getting NetConnection.Call.Failed?
How do I resolve this error?
Any feedback you can give is appreciated

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The app you are using doesn't contain the method being requested `onClientBWCheck`. Two options here:

1. Add the method to `com.videowhisper.Application`.
2. Remove the call to `onClientBWCheck` in the client-side application.